# Python: Efficently extract a single value for every group

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add a description column to a dataframe that is built by grouping items from another dataframe.

```
grouped= df1.groupby('item')
list= grouped['total'].agg(np.sum)
list= list.reset_index()
```

to assign a description label to every item I've come up with this solution:

```
def des(item):
        return df1['description'].loc[df1['item']== item].iloc[0]

list['description'] = list['item'].apply(des)
```

it works but it takes an enourmous amount of time to execute.
I'd like to do something like that

```
list=list.assign(description= df1['description'].loc[df1['item']==list['item']]
```

or

```
list=list.assign(description= df1['description'].loc[df1['item'].isin(list['item'])]
```

Theese are very wrong but hope you get the idea, hoping there is some pandas stuff that do the trick more efficently but can't find it 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by `dict` of functions - for column `total` `sum` and for  `description` [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df1.groupby('item', as_index=False).agg({'total':'sum', 'description':'first'})
```

Also dont use variable name `list`, because `list` is python code reserved word.

**Sample**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'description':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'total':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'item':list('aaabbb')})
print (df1)
   B description item  total
0  4           a    a      5
1  5           b    a      3
2  4           c    a      6
3  5           d    b      9
4  5           e    b      2
5  4           f    b      4

df = df1.groupby('item', as_index=False).agg({'total':'sum', 'description':'first'})
print (df)
  item  total description
0    a     14           a
1    b     15           d
```

Comment: regarding ''list'': prior to posting I've changed some of the the variables names in hope to make clearer the code, didn't think too much while doing it, thanks for pointing it out!